# On Windows 7, is there a way to lock an application window's Z-order when it opens?

Tags: windows-7, rocketdock

I removed the taskbar and replaced it with rocketdock.  I want to get Windows to not go under it like it does with the taskbar.

Comment: Your question's title mentions window _size_ but the content of the question seems to be asking about Z-order (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order).  Which is it?

Comment: I think Z-Order may be the answer.  How can I edit this?

Comment: You can't.  I did it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This seems not to be built-in to RocketDock, but there is an add-on for this functionality.

http://rocketdock.com/addon/misc/10809

Answer (score 0):

I'm running RocketDock 1.3.5, you're instructions may vary.  This is what I do:

1. Bring up RocketDock Settings (I do this by clicking on the Wrench Icon in the dock)
2. Then select Position (The blue X with arrows)
3. Then select Layering and set it to "Always on Top"

This should keep it "always on top" but will not make it always visible if that is your desire.

The problem I have is that some applications seem to show up on top of the dock regardless of this setting.  I can see the dock show up when I move my mouse to the top of the screen, but I cannot always interact with it.  To solve that problem, I use a freeware called [Desktop Coral](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/desktopcoral/).  It docks a very small window on the side of the screen where you have RockDock.  Whenever RocketDock is hidden behind something, I always have a few pixels available where I can click it.

This is not perfect, because in a two monitor setup Desktop Coral is showing up on the wrong monitor; and you are giving up a few pixels of screen real estate.

I don't think this is exactly what you're after; but I thought these instructions may help others.